# Python Dataframe sort the dataframe using pd.cut range column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a big dataframe and I created a temperature range column by using `pd.cut`. This is fine. Now I want to know the minimum range in that min-max range column. So, I can use this column to sort the dataframe

My code:

```
# Goal: sort below dataframe by the 'temp_range' columns
# The column should be sorted as '-60-50','-10-0','0-10','20-30'
xdf = pd.DataFrame(data={'temp_range':['-10-0','20-30','-60-50','0-10']})
xdf['Min. temp range']= xdf['temp_range'].apply(lambda x:x[:3])
xdf
```

Present solution:

```
    temp_range  Min. temp range
0   -10-0   -10
1   20-30   20-
2   -60-50  -60
3   0-10    0-1
```

Expected solution:

```
    temp_range  Min. temp range
0   -10-0   -10
1   20-30   20
2   -60-50  -60
3   0-10    0
```

Sort this expected solution by the Min. temp range column

```
xdf.sort_values('Min. temp range')
    temp_range  Min. temp range
0   -60-50  -60
1   -10-0   -10
2   0-10    0
3   20-30   20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
xdf['Min. temp range'] = xdf['temp_range'].str.extract('^(-?\d+)')
```

Output:

```
  temp_range Min. temp range
0      -10-0             -10
1      20-30              20
2     -60-50             -60
3       0-10               0
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LjUsdc/1)

If you don't need the column and just want to sort:

```
xdf.sort_values(by='temp_range', key=lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s.str.extract('^(-?\d+)', expand=False)))
```

Output:

```
  temp_range
2     -60-50
0      -10-0
3       0-10
1      20-30
```

Comment: How to navigate when there are duplicates. I want them to be included in the data. The goal is to plot histogram showing percentage samples in the each bin or range.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you should probably open a new question with all details ;)

Comment: @Mainland I've seen your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75951773/16343464) and I believe my last command should work for that. Didn't it? You my want to provide a reproducible dataset in the other question.