# Plot temperature barplot with sorted axis categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I want to show number of samples in specific range of the temperature. The problem is, x-axis of the plot is not arranged in the proper order: lowest range first (negative temperatures ) and bigger range next. In the below plot, -5750 is lowest temperature. But it appears in the middle. It is to be first one on x-axis.

```
  fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
  ax = sns.histplot(df,x='Temperature range (C)',stat='percent',ax=ax)
  ax.set_yscale('log')
  plt.ylabel('log(percentage samples)')
  plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
  plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `'Temperature range (C)'` are strings.

Comment: @BigBen It is indeed a string. Reason: I am doing pd.cut to assign range to each sample. There are empty samples. For instance, as you can see, no samples between -5000 - -80. Converting it to strings eliminates plotting these empty ranges.

Comment: Order the column with pandas.Categorical or use the ordered=True parameter in .cut.

Comment: A histogram has a continues axis. This has a discrete axis, as such, it's a bar plot. Technically it's a countplot, implemented with histplot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by temperature before hand might help

```
df.sort_values(by = 'Temperature range (C)' , inplace = True)
```

Comment: `'Temperature range (C)'` are strings.